# First eigenvalue of $-\Delta$ in unit square $(0,1)\times (0,1)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

I need to calculate the first eigenvalue of Laplacian $-\Delta$ for unit square $(0,1)\times (0,1)$. As a hint I got that consider the function $u(x, y)=\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$. All tools I have are the eigenvalue equation $-\Delta u=\lambda u$ in $\Omega$, $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ and the Rayleigh quotient $$Q(w)=\frac
{\int_\Omega |\nabla w|^2}{\int_\Omega w^2},$$
and I know that $\min Q$ is the smallest eigenvalue. I calculated the eigenvalue corresponding to the hint and got $\lambda=2\pi^2$. Somehow I should show that all the other eigenvalues are bounded below by $2\pi^2$. I tried some integration tricks but they were of no use. Hints/help is welcome.

Comment: This problem is some solving by showing the inverse of $-\Delta$ is a compact operator

Comment: @GuyFsone we haven't used any functional analytic tools in the class so there must be an easier way

Answer (score 0):

you can try to solve to solve this problems by variable separation you can put $u(x,y)=f(x)\times g(y)$ you prjectes this in your equation you find solution with $\lambda$ unkown and you can use the the boundary condition to find the $\lambda$
it's easy juste start

Comment: but that's just one class of solutions to the problem, how do I know that every solution is of the form $u(x, y)=f(x)g(y)$?

Comment: the sulotion of this problems is unique so you can write the solution as you wich but your function should verify the equation $-\Delta u=\lamba u$ and the boundary condition

Comment: And how do you know that there are no other functions satisfying the eigenvalue equation for smaller $\lambda$?

Comment: solution is not necessarily unique since there might be other functions corresponding to the same eigenvalue. the first eigenspace is though 1-dimensional so the functions are equal up to constant.

Comment: the solutions of the problemes are $(u,\lambda)\in H^[1}_0(\Omega)\times \mathbb{R}$

Comment: it'is clear that if $(u,\lambda) $is a solution of Dirichlet laplacian and you take a a real number (au,\lambda) is also a solution

Comment: @abla so you are talking about weak solutions? maybe I didn't emphasize it well, I'm considering classical solutions

Comment: the uniqueness is in both directions weak or classical

Comment: as a references you can see [courant hilbert methods of mathematical physics] they solve solve exactly you problemes